# Can't upload a file to google drive using google service account

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api

I have an issue during uploading a file to Google Drive.

I created a service account , added google drive api to the project, share a folder (that file will be sending) to service account id.

I did all these things but I can't upload a file.

```
The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is NotFound. File not found: 1JlGO5gas321321(testId).
```

Access level for this service account is a contributor. When I tested this solution on free version of google drive (with access editor) everything is working.

I am using .net 6 for this.

here is my code:

```
   public static async Task<UploadStatus> SaveToGoogleCloud(string csvLines, string fileTitle,string driveFolderId)
   {
       var loggedCredential = GoogleAuthentication.Login();
       using var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = loggedCredential });

       var csvMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
       {
           Name = fileTitle,
           Parents = new List<string>() { driveFolderId },
       };

       var fsSource = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvLines ?? ""));

       var request = driveService.Files.Create(csvMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
       request.Fields = "*";
       var results = await request.UploadAsync();

       return results.Status;
   }
```

Maybe someone had similar issue and know how to solve it ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Code is added to the question

Comment: where in that code is it giving you the notfound error

Comment: after this line of code:

  `var results = await request.UploadAsync();`

I receive results with info, that file not found

Answer (score 0):

okay ignore my last answer apparently i shouldn't try to go from memory any more

would you mind adding this before your return so we can try to debug this

```
    // Make the asynchronous call to upload the file.
    var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    // Handle upload status.
    if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
    {
        // TODO: handle a file upload error.
        Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
    }

    var fileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
    Console.WriteLine($"fileId {fileId}" );
```

Comment: no worries :) I receive "not found bug" after call to this:
   `var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);`

i receive this message:
`The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is NotFound. File not found: 1JlGOTEST5i9SBI3A.`
from line:
 ` Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");`

I am just wondering that maybe it's something related to setting is google admin portal but I think that I added everything there

Comment: are you sure you shared that directory with the service account.   well your not using domain wide delegation if thats what your trying to do.  for this to work as is you would have to share the folder with the servcie account

Comment: I shared that directory for service account. This soultion it works for different google env (free version)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue.

```
 request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
```

was missed